# Finding value of a summation series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

> Find the value of
>   $$\sum^{\infty}_{i=0}\sum^{\infty}_{j=0}\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}{1\over3^i3^j3^k}$$
>   Where $i\ne j,j\ne k,k\ne i$.

What does this notion means? How can we write this in expanded form? What does the inequality between $i,j,k$ mean? And most importantly how to solve this type of series(hints would be better)?

Comment: You allow $i=k\ne j$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown- No, thats a problem.

Comment: What does $i\neq j\neq k$ mean? Does it mean that in (i,j,k) there is no value occuring twice or three times?

Comment: If so, you should edit the question to make that clear.

Comment: You should write $i\neq j, j\neq k, k\neq i$, if you want to convey no two of $i, j, k$ are equal to one another.  What you've written is ambiguous, and hence meaningless.

Comment: I have a feeling it's equal to $3\sum^{\infty}_{i=3}{1\over3^{i}}$

Comment: A technique similar to inclusion-exclusion should work here.  First find the value of $\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{3^{i+j+k}}$ (*this can be done quickly by factoring and knowledge of geometric series*).  You may then recognize that you added several terms that you shouldn't have, so subtract those where $i=j$ as well as those where $i=k$ and those where $j=k$.  You recognize further that you subtracted those where $i=j=k$ a total of three times when we intended to subtract them only once, so add the sum where $i=j=k$ back in twice more.

Comment: I get $27(\tfrac 1{13} - \tfrac 1{16})$

Comment: @amsmath- Correct... Any hint or solution.

Comment: As an alternative to the excellent strategy suggested by @JMoravitz , you could also recognize that (thanks to symmetries of exchanging variables) your series is equal to $6\times \sum_{i\ge0} \sum_{j>i} \sum_{k>j} 1/3^i3^j3^k$, and then evaluate the sums individually from inner to outer (they're all geometric series).

Comment: duplicate: [post 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2277752/evaluate-the-following-triple-summation), [post 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2316863/find-value-of-this-triple-summation/2317261#2317261), [post 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2877018/help-in-multiple-sigma-question/2877028#2877028)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First ignore the restriction $i \ne j \ne k$. The result is $\left( \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{3}} \right)^3 = \frac{27}{8}$, since this is simply the geometric series $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{3^i}$ raised to the power 3.

Now subtract the three series that come from the conditions $i=j, i=k, j=k$. These are each equal to $\frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{3}} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{9}} = \frac{27}{16}$.

Finally add back two times the series coming from the terms with $i = j = k$, since it has been subtracted three times and should only be subtracted once. This series is equal to $\frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{27}} = \frac{27}{26}$.

The result is 
$$
\frac{27}{8} - 3 \cdot\frac{27}{16} + 2 \frac{27}{26} \approx 0.38942\dots
$$

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestion given in the comments we have that

$$\sum^{\infty}_{i=0}\sum^{\infty}_{j=0}\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}{1\over3^i3^j3^k}
=\left(\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}{1\over3^k}\right)^3
-3\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}{1\over3^k}\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}{1\over9^k}
+2\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}{1\over{27}^k}$$

and by geometric series

$$\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}{1\over3^k}=\frac1{1-\frac13}=\frac32$$

$$\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}{1\over9^k}=\frac1{1-\frac19}=\frac98$$

$$\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}{1\over{27}^k}=\frac1{1-\frac1{27}}=\frac{27}{26}$$

Comment: How does $i\ne j\ne k$ come into this?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I thought it was simply a condition for independency of i,j,k. Is it wrong?

Comment: @gimusi-Yes, answer is 81/208

Answer (score 1):

We can respect the conditions $i\ne j,j\ne k,k\ne i$ by adding up over $0\leq i<j<k<\infty$ and since the order counts we multiply with $3!$.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{3!}&\color{blue}{\sum_{0\leq i<j<k<\infty}\frac{1}{3^{i+j+k}}}\\
> &=3!\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=i+1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=j+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^{i+j+k}}\\
> &=3!\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=i+1}^{\infty}\sum_{\color{blue}{k=0}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^{i+2j+k+1}}\tag{$k\to k+j+1$}\\
> &=3!\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{\color{blue}{j=0}}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^{3i+2j+k+3}}\tag{$j\to j+i+1$}\\
> &=3!\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{27}}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{9}}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{3}}\cdot\frac{1}{27}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{81}{208}\approx 0.38942}
> \end{align*}